# Angular JS Component Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, binding, components

I have following component:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("application_module")
        .component('tab', {
            controller: 'TabCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'app/component/application/app-header/tab/tab.html',
            bindings: {
                'pageName': '<',
                'pageNo': '<'
            }
        });
})();
```

Its html template:

```
<md-nav-item md-nav-click="$ctrl.goto($ctrl.pageNo)"
             name="$ctrl.pageNo">
    {{$ctrl.pageName}}
</md-nav-item>
```

Its controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("application_module")
        .controller('TabCtrl', TabCtrl);

    function TabCtrl() {
        let self = this;
    }
})();
```

I try to use it from the following code:

```
<tab pageName="EmployeeInfo" pageNo="page1"></tab>
```

I don't see `pageName` and `pageNo` in final html of rendered page. What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with camelCase, we used lowcase:

```
<tab pagename="EmployeeInfo" pageno="page1"></tab>
```

and in component:

```
bindings: {
    'pagename': '@',
    'pageno': '@'
}
```

And it works ok now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the binding attribute names to use hyphens and lower case characters. So for your example:

`<tab page-name="EmployeeInfo" page-no="page1"></tab>`